specify java minor version in maven-compiler-plugin
from the link here
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-release.html
it mentions

the javac executable can accept the --release option to specify
against which Java SE release you want to build the project.

but most example just use the whole number 11, 17,  what if we want to specify the minor version also?
e.g. is this feasible?
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>17.0.12</release>                        
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

As I found that after I change the  from 17 to 17.0.12, my webapp fail to start.
The error is
Failed to define class pkg1.web.ABCContextListener in Module "deployment.ABCEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.ABC-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link pkg1/web/ABCContextListener (Module "deployment.ABCEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.ABC-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader): org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1090)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:351)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:276)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:79)
at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:765)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:192)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:21)
at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:14)
at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:84)
at org.jboss.as.ee@28.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
at org.jboss.as.server@20.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
at org.jboss.msc@1.5.0.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1590)
at org.jboss.msc@1.5.0.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1553)
at org.jboss.msc@1.5.0.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1411)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)

My spring version is 6.1.7 ,should compatible with 17.0.12?

What happens if you change it back to "17"?

then everything returns to normal, the web apps can run successfully

It doesn't do what you think it do. It  is not JDK version. It is language specification version. You can use JDK 23 and set it to 8. In result compiler will use JLS 8 and output class files with version 52.

@talex Then can I assume if I use 17, then it can also safely run on jdk 17.0.12 (or any jdk 17.x.xx)?

@user1169587 Yes, generated code should be binary compatible with those versions.

before the  options, there are -source and -target options, this also refer to java language specification JLS, not JDK version?

It doesn't do what you think it do.
It is not JDK version. It is language specification version. You can use JDK 23 and set it to 8. In result compiler will use JLS 8 and output class files with version 52.
